# Selenium doesnt click menu element even though it's there

Tags: internet-explorer, user-interface, selenium, automation

I'm trying to automate a scenario where I'm mousing over one element and then clicking another element from that submenu. I'm using CSS selectors and doing testing for IE webdriver.

Our soft is providing 4 different languages to navigate. My code works for all 3, except for 1. So again, code is generic and doesn't change for either of the languages. CSS selectors are the same, and it forks for 3 out of 4 languages available. I tested each 20 times and 3 languages pass 100% the one that fail = always fails.

When I do `element.getText() =` on the one that is failing, I can see that i'm at the correct element. The text is what it should be. When i do `element.click()`, I get nowhere.
I tried `action.moveToElement.click()`, doubleClicking it. It all works for 3 other languages, but not for the one that is failing. So I'm very positive my code is ok. If I do it manually there are no problems, I only see it using IE driver.

How I fixed it:

As a work around, I'm reading location of element and then using java.Robot to move actual mouse to my sub-menu item and clicking it. Now it works, but I still want to understand why I ran into this problem.

Has anyone else experienced this?

I don't really like my solution, because now I'm failing on tests if IE browser is opened on second monitor and my X and Y locations are related to main monitor.

I'd love to add html as well but it is pretty complicated and page takes it as a html and doesn't display it.

My code for that part it there:

```
element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span[widgetid=\"app_schedulesAndPlanningApp\"].dijit.dijitReset.dijitButton")));

action.moveToElement(element, 1, 1).perform();

try {
    robot = new Robot();
    element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.appSubMenu ul li.subApp:nth-child(4)"));
    location = element.getLocation();
    robot.mouseMove(location.getX() + 20, location.getY() + 80);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
```

Where you see Robot i used to do element.click();

Comment: Seems very odd. Would you mind adding a HTML snippet + the selectors you're using?

Comment: What is also odd is that in another case i'm using this :          element = wait
    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By
      .cssSelector("span[widgetid=\"app_schedulesAndPlanningApp\"].dijit.dijitReset.dijitButton")));
  action.moveToElement(element).perform();
  element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By
    .cssSelector("div.appSubMenu ul li:nth-child(5)")));
  element.click();
    So it's pretty much the same menu, just different submenu item and this code works 100% for each langguage

Comment: Paste the HTML (while editing the question), select it and hit the 'Code Sample' button, that should format it so it is displayed. Also, what error does the failing test give?

Comment: will update HTML in the am. It doesnt fail. but also it doesn't click submenu element.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that the .click() method is not always reliable.  You might try just setting up a method that re-tries your .click() action until it actually works.  That worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, that is a very good idea, but i'm already doing it. I'm retrying up to 5 times. I think i'll let this one go.. Just as i told, i know i found the element, I have retry on clicking it and still i get no result for only this one page only in Spanish language.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the similar issue during while working with IE webdriver. My code worked on firefox for a dropdown but failed on IE event though webdriver was pointing to right element.

My solution was to put somea second wait by using `Thread.Sleep(100);` after clicking the dropdown menu. Something like this.

```
Click on Menu or dorpdown box element
Thread.sleep(100); //in milliseconds
Click on dropdown element form menu or dorpdown
```

hope this will solve your problem with IE.

Comment: I can see the element using other 3 languages, and when i get name of the button - it is what it should be. It has nothing to do with sleep time.. Thanks anyways